# Mongoose Update Field With the Item of the Another Field That is Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am building an Expense Tracker Application, There is a User Collection that has fields like Name, Amount, Expenses Array, Incomes Array, and So On.

> My Database Is Mongo Db with Mongoose and the Server Is Written In Express.

Here Is A Screenshot Of the Database after The Values are Filled
[image: MongoDB Database Screenshot]

I am trying to Implement a Route in which The User Can Delete an Expense and After Deleting the Expense I want to update the Balance and make the Balance = Balance + Expense. I am able to Delete and Expense But Not able to Update the Balance as I do not know how to retrieve the Balance from the Deleted Expense

---

Here is the Delete Route :

```
router.delete("/", (req, res) => {
  const { UserID, ExpenseID } = req.query;
  const query = {
    $pull: {
      Expenses: { _id: ExpenseID },
    },
  };
  User.findByIdAndUpdate(UserID, query)
  
});
```

---

I want to add a Mongoose Method which Will Fetch the Expense Amount from the Received Expense Id and Store it in a variable and After the Expense Gets Deleted, I want to call a method to update the balance of the User in the Promise.

Here is an example of what I intend to do

```
// Deletes An Expense
router.delete("/", (req, res) => {
  const { UserID, ExpenseID } = req.query;
  const query = {
    $pull: {
      Expenses: { _id: ExpenseID },
    },
  };
  User.find({/*Some Query Which Will Return me The Provided Expense ID's Amount*/})
  User.findByIdAndUpdate(UserID, query)
  .then(() => {
    // Once I find and Remove the Expense, Now I would Like to Update the Users Balance
    // NewBalance = OldBalance + Expense ID's Amount Returned by the Find Method
    // Here I would Call another User.find method to update the Users Balance
  })
});
```

---

Let's Say From the Above Database Snap, I want to delete the Expenses (Starting From 0) 1st Object Element, Name: Uber Fare, I will send the Object Id which is 6091f725403c2e1b8c18dda3 to the Server and should Expect my Balance to Increase from 48495 to 49695

Comment: Please share code instead of screenshots.

Comment: I have replaced the Screenshots with the code @hhharsha36

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is:

1. Fetch user document with `UserID`
2. Find the expense with `ExpenseID`
3. Update the `Balance` with the expense amount
4. Remove expense from `Expenses` array
5. Save user document

```
router.put("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { UserID, ExpenseID } = req.query;
    let user = await User.find({ _id: UserID });
    index = user.Expenses.findIndex((expense) => expense._id === ExpenseID);
    if (index != -1) {
      user.Balance += user.Expenses[index].Amount;
      user.Expenses.splice(index, 1);
    }
    await user.save();
    return res.status(200).json({ success: true, user: user });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).json({ success: false, error: error })
  }
});
```

**NOTE**: Since this is updating the document, I configured `put` method instead of `delete` on the router.

Comment: I get back a Response which is                                                                                          {
    "success": false,
    "error": {}
}

Comment: can you console.log(error) before the `return res.status(400).json({ success: false, error: error })` and add it here?

Answer (score 1):

Create a `static method` for the `schema` like so

```js
userSchema.statics.deleteExpenseUpdateBalance = async function (userID, expenseID) {
  const user = await this.findOne({ _id: userID });
  let userExpenses = user.Expenses;
  userExpenses.forEach((expense) => {
    if (expense._id === expenseID) {
      let amount = expense.Amount;
      let index = userExpenses.indexOf(expense);
      userExpenses.splice(index, 1);
      user.Balance += amount;
      return;
    }
  });

  user.save((err) => {
      if (err) {
          console.log(err)
      }
  });
};
```

Access this in your route handler

```js
router.delete("/", async (req, res) => {
  const { UserID, ExpenseID } = req.query;
  let result = await User.deleteExpenseUpdateBalance(UserID, ExpenseID)
});
```

This `static method` will `remove` the expense and `update` the balance.
Explanation: The `static method` just finds the user and iterates through their `Expenses` and removes the required `expense` and the `amount` is just added to the `balance`. Finally the `user.save()` method is called to save all documents.

**NOTE: Use this only if you are sure that the expenseID exists in the Expense array, otherwise you'll just have to add an extra check for that in the static method**

Also put the static method in the file where you create your `schema` and `model` in between both of their creations i.e after you've created the userSchema and before you finalise it into a `model`.

Comment: Where do I have to create the Static Method? Inside the same File as the route or Should I create a separate file which has the static method?

Comment: Create the `static method` in the file where you have created the `schema`. I've mentioned the specificities in the last para of my answer.

Comment: Is there a way I can implement the Same above code but all inside the Route Handler, Or is it necessary to create a static method and call it from the handler?

Comment: You can put all of this in route handler. Just copy all the logic inside the `static method` and put it inside the handler. But it is better to do it with separate files. It is easier to update, debug, read and manage everything overall. Also, creating that `static method` allows you to use it in other places as well if you need it.